Particle Marginal Metropolis Hastings - How to multiply the proposal distribution by the distribution of x?
When we are using particle marginal metropolis hastings, we will approximate the distribution of x with particle filter, in this pdf written below says:

In such situations it
is natural to suggest the following form of proposal density for an MH update: $q(\{\theta^*, x_{1:T}^*\}|\{\theta,x_{1:T}\}) = q(\theta^*, \theta) * \pi(x_{1:T}^*|y_{1:T},\theta^*)$

How to multiply the proposal distribution by the distribution of x?
$q(\{\theta^*, x_{1:T}^*\}|\{\theta,x_{1:T}\}) = q(\theta^*, \theta) * \pi(x_{1:T}^*|y_{1:T},\theta^*)$
Can someone give me an example how this multiplication is done?

https://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~doucet/andrieu_doucet_holenstein_PMCMC.pdf
